# Multiple inputs in a Bootbox

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

How can I have 2 inputs instead of just one in Bootstrap's Bootbox?

I need to receive 2 values in a modal dialog.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Actually, there is a simpler way which doesn't require you to modify bootbox code.

The string you pass at the bootbox creation doesn't have to be only text: it can also be html code. That means you can include pretty much everything in the box.

To put a custom form in a bootbox, you can then create it as follow :

```
bootbox.confirm("<form id='infos' action=''>\
    First name:<input type='text' name='first_name' /><br/>\
    Last name:<input type='text' name='last_name' />\
    </form>", function(result) {
        if(result)
            $('#infos').submit();
});
```

Comment: How would you access the form contents?

Answer (score 8):

I just made function for that, check it out - [here](https://github.com/kittee/bootbox/tree/form)

Usage example

```
bootbox.form({
    title: 'User details',
    fields: {
        name: {
            label: 'Name',
            value: 'John Connor',
            type:  'text'
        },
        email: {
            label: 'E-mail',
            type:  'email',
            value: 'johnconnor@skynet.com'
        },
        type: {
            label: 'Type',
            type:  'select',
            options: [
                {value: 1, text: 'Human'},
                {value: 2, text: 'Robot'}
            ]
        },
        alive: {
            label: 'Is alive',
            type: 'checkbox',
            value: true
        },
        loves: {
            label: 'Loves',
            type: 'checkbox',
            value: ['bike','mom','vg'],
            options: [
                {value: 'bike', text: 'Motorbike'},
                {value: 'mom', text: 'His mom'},
                {value: 'vg', text: 'Video games'},
                {value: 'kill', text: 'Killing people'}
            ]
        },
        passwd: {
            label: 'Password',
            type: 'password'
        },
        desc: {
            label: 'Description',
            type: 'textarea'
        }
    },
    callback: function (values) {
        console.log(values)
    }
})
```

Comment: Cool feature!  text inputs are broken if you try and add placeholders, any plans on updating it @kitty?

Comment: @Havihavi I will certainly take a look on it, please describe the problem on https://github.com/kittee/bootbox/issues

Answer (score 6):

For me, this is the cleanest way to do it :

```
var form = $('<form><input name="usernameInput"/></form>');
bootbox.alert(form,function(){
    var username = form.find('input[name=usernameInput]').val();
    console.log(username);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Create hidden div with form in HTML and inject this html to bootbox message. Snippet below.

```js
var buttonClick = function() {
  var bootboxHtml = $('#js-exampleDiv').html().replace('js-exampleForm', 'js-bootboxForm');
  bootbox.confirm(bootboxHtml, function(result) {
    console.log($('#ex1', '.js-bootboxForm').val());
    console.log($('#ex2', '.js-bootboxForm').val());
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<div id="js-exampleDiv" hidden>
  <form class="js-exampleForm">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input placeholder="Example placeholder 1" id="ex1" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input placeholder="Example placeholder 2" id="ex2" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<button onclick="buttonClick();">
  Open bootbox confirm dialog.
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I prefer this method since the HTML is not a constructed string, making it easier to manipulate, load values into a select input, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write your own function which will load dialog function from bootbox.

The easiest way is to copy prompt function from source: https://raw.github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/v3.2.0/bootbox.js

and change this part for adding new input (or whatever you need)

```
    // let's keep a reference to the form object for later
    var form = $("<form></form>");
    form.append("<input autocomplete=off type=text value='" + defaultVal + "' />");
```

and this part for getting result:

```
    var confirmCallback = function() {
        if (typeof cb === 'function') {
            return cb(form.find("input[type=text]").val());
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic example for what you need (using knockout)

```
<button data-bind="click: select">Button</button>
<script type="text/html" id="add-template">
    <div style="display:none">
        <input data-bind='value: name' placeholder="Name">
    </div>
</script>


var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.select = function () {
        var messageTemplate = $($("#add-template").html());
        ko.applyBindings(self, messageTemplate.get(0));
        messageTemplate.show();
        bootbox.confirm({
                title: "Add new",
                message:  messageTemplate,
                callback: function (value) {
                    // do something
                }
            });
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Just add as many fields and bind them in the view model

http://jsfiddle.net/6vb7e224/2/

Answer (score 0):

**haradwaith** Has the best solution for posting form data from a bootbox. Because it works, it's simple and because he demonstrates how to Actually Submit the Form. His solution:

```
bootbox.confirm("<form id='infos' action=''>\
    First name:<input type='text' name='first_name' /><br/>\
    Last name:<input type='text' name='last_name' />\
    </form>", function(result) {
        if(result)
            $('#infos').submit();
});
```

Moving the <form> tag outside of the bootbox object allows the use of PHP when posting to self and to include hidden inputs without all the clutter.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" id="infos">
<input type=hidden form="infos" name="created" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>" />
</form>
```

Now you can check for $_POST['created']

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['created'])){
     echo "Timestamp: ".$_POST['created']; // great things happen here
    }
?>
```

You can create the form anywhere in the body tag, it won't display because the inputs are hidden.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old now, but this is the way I've done it. I think this way is great for larger forms as putting all of the `HTML` in `JavaScript` can get ugly pretty quick.

This example uses `Bootstrap` but the idea is the same. Create a hidden form in `HTML` and then select it using `JavaScript` or `JQuery`.

HTML:

```
<div id="hiddenForm" class="hidden">
    <form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="FirstName" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="LastName" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">City</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="City" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">State</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="State" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript Version:

```
var form = document.getElementById("hiddenForm").innerHTML;
bootbox.confirm({
    message: form,
    callback: function (result) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

JQuery Version:

```
var form = $("#hiddenForm").html();
bootbox.confirm({
    message: form,
    callback: function (result) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

**Note:**

When you try to serialize the form for posting, you'll have to make sure you are actually targeting the right form. `$("#myForm").serialize()` will most likely not work as it will grab the actual `HTML` form that you built earlier. So instead, you should do something like `$(".bootbox-body #myForm").serialize()` to get the current form's values.